# How to change the password of a (vsftpd) FTP account when 'passwd' isnt working

Tags: linux, ftp, password, vsftpd, passwd

Kinda newbie here,

I have a server which uses vsftpd.
I changed the password of user 'aa' from the root account with 'passwd aa', which changed the SSH password for user 'aa', but not for his FTP account.

I can't seem to find much other info on changing a vsftpd password.

Any tips?

Comment: Look at what authentication method `vsftpd` is using, DB, or config files maybe?

Comment: Are you using a management panel like Webmin, cPanel or Plesk?  Many of these do not create system users but have users specific to FTP.

Comment: I tried that Nick, all I can find is some files in /etc/vsftpd/. there are some useraccount files there, but no passwords. and no management panels jeff.

Answer (score 1):

If your FTP server is using virtual users (check `local_enable` in the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file, see `man vsftpd.conf`), you may have a `login.txt` file under /`etc/vsftpd/`, which is of the following form :

```
login1
password1
login2
password2
etc.
```

In this case you have to edit it, then use the following command to update the DB :

```
db4.7_load -T -t hash -f /etc/vsftpd/login.txt /etc/vsftpd/login.db
```

(you may have to replace `db4.7_load` by your version of `dbXX_load`).

Comment: I don't see these `login.txt` and `login.db` in `man vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: @ziyuang The reference to `man vsftpd.conf` is only to give more details about `local_enable`.